# Saving status of all the task in xcom as soon as it gets completed a in airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

i am writing a dag and i want to save the status of a task with their taskid in a dictonary in XCOM, the status can be success or failed or anything.

For example below are the two task

```
def task_18(ti):
    print("TASK 18 COMPLETE")
def task_19(ti):
    print("TASK 19 COMPLETE")

opr_task_17 = PythonOperator(task_id='task.id.number.18',python_callable=task_18)
opr_task_18 = PythonOperator(task_id='task.id.number.19',python_callable=task_19)
```

what i want is as soon as the task 18, 19 is completed then the dictonary must look somethhing like this.

```
{task.id.number.18: success/failed, task.id.number.19: success/failed}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that an XCom is the most suited, since the status of tasks from any given DagRun is dynamically available at any time.

That being said it is straight forward to access this information:

```py
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

@dag(
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 4, 18),
    catchup=False,
)
def example_dag():
    @task()
    def task_one(**context):
        print("task one")

    @task()
    def task_two(**context):
        raise AirflowFailException()

    @task(trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE)
    def access_status(**context):
        dag_run = context["dag_run"]
        print({task.task_id: task.state for task in dag_run.get_task_instances()})

    [task_one(), task_two()] >> access_status()


example_dag_run = example_dag()
```

The output of `access_status` is:

```
{'access_status': 'running', 'task_two': 'failed', 'task_one': 'success'}
```

When you pass `**context` to a `PythonOperator` the same variables that are available to the templating engine are passed in (as well as some other parameters). You can view a list of all variables on `**context` here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html.

Here we have used this to get the `DagRun` object for the current Dag.

The most useful are the `DagRun` and `TaskInstance` objects.

All properties/methods available on `DagRun` are here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html?highlight=dag+run#airflow.models.dagrun.DagRun

You can see that `get_task_instances` is a method on the dag. This returns a iterable of all `TaskInstance` objects for the dag.

And you can view all properties/methods for a `TaskInstance` here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html?highlight=taskinstance#airflow.models.taskinstance.TaskInstance

You can see that `task_id` and `state` are properties on a `TaskInstance`.

These properties are all stored in the Airflow Database. This is where Airflow looks up this information when you try to access it.

If you have configured access to the database to you can progmatically access all of this information:

```sql
select dag_id, task_id, state from task_instance where run_id='manual__2022-10-22T15:42:56.692444+00:00'
```

[image]